# Remove a node from the DOM upon successful onClick event, vuejs3

Tags: vuejs3

Here's a fragment of my component:-

```
<template>
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <table class=" table">
        <thead class="table-light">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Created at</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <template :key="foo" v-for="categories in info">
            <template v-for="attributes in categories">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ attributes.attributes.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ attributes.attributes.status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ formatDate(attributes.attributes.created_at) }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button @click="deleteCategory(attributes.id)">delete</button>
                    </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </template>
      </tbody>
...
</template>
```

```
deleteCategory(id) {
  axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/' + id, {
         headers: {
           Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('apiToken')
        }
    })
     .then((response) => {
         alert('Category successfully deleted');
         this.foo.forceUpdate();

   }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
   });
},
```

On click of `deleteCategory` my code deletes the record in the db successfully. I'd like to reload/refresh the component thud removing the deleted record from the dom following my alert? I'm trying:-

```
this.foo.forceUpdate();
this.foo.$forceUpdate();
```

Comment: One way of refreshing the page following onClick: `window.location.reload();`

Comment: I think if you need to reload the page, you have not understand, what a reactive framework does … Nevertheless, what you need to do is, to have a list of all your items in a reactive array and if you delete an item on the server, you either need to refresh your reactive list or fetch all categories again (which will add more load to the server and it's not really like green it).

Comment: Going off your other question, looks like you are storing api data in `info` variable, then have v-for with info to get your posts.

When you delete a post, you can either delete post from `info` variable, or refetch and reassign api data to `info`. This will make your DOM reactivly update because your array now does not have the deleted post.

Vue in general is data driven, as in you should be updating related variables, and Vue will do the rest with DOM. It does give you tools for some very edgy cases, but this here is not one of those edge cases.